# firebase setup with react with init or without?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to tie my react app to firebase,
I understand the general idea behind but the it seems like there are few different binding
options depending on how much you want get into functionality of firebase.

0.0 basically without registering a firebase app in the project to my react app and using any service lets say from authentication or database. Ive been able to use make POST and GET request as well as sign up and in users without regiestering an app from firebase website.
just have to use the end points given by the service you wish to use.

1.0 I guess this is the more proper way which registering a firebase app to my react app
either by using npm or script/cdn. I am new to firebase so i did not know that i had to do this.

2.0 basically the same step as 1.0 but also initializing/configuring firebase app(?) with Firebase CLI which creates things like

A firebase.json configuration file that lists your project configuration.
A .firebaserc file that stores your project aliases.

this is now where i get confused as to how to go about combiniing with my react app.

for example, locally, react app is running on port 3000 but when i use CLI's firebase emulators: start script, what will happen to my react app which is running on 3000.

How do you guys set this up correctly? i guess it depend on how much backend i want to use but what i need firebase for mostly is to use authentication and database...